# Error Connection refused for ionic 2 starter project via cli command

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am facing an issue while trying to download the ionic starter template using CLI . I mentioned the error below I am getting , also I set the proxy as well for `get proxy command` am getting `http://proxy.ww.com` . Please suggest me I am  doing wrong anything. Also  my ionic and cordova versions are ionic `3.9.2` and cordova `7.0.1`

Error in command prompt :

```
C:\Users\SU384200>ionic start helpworld --blank

? What starter would you like to use: blank
√ Creating directory .\helpworld - done!
[INFO] Fetching app base
       (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.tar.gz)
× Downloading - failed!
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.30.253.112:443
```

Answer (score 0):

To be clear with your question, If you want create a ionic 2 project, then you need to go with the command

```
ionic start helpworld --blank --v2
```

Add --v2 flag for ionic 2 project.

For your Error there can be possibilities like :

1. Github.com may be block in your corporate network.
2. Can be problem with your SSL Certificates.